# DDD Database first . How to handle aggregates

Tags: c#, entity-framework, domain-driven-design

I'm trying to learn the concept of DDD. I have made a project which i use the database first approach.
In the infrastructure i have added an edmx file witch i have chosen to auto generate the entites. Now in the "Domain" I'm trying to create aggregates.

But here i got some problems. I´m trying to create a aggregate named "User" but User already exists in the entites that the ef autogenerated. Should i rename the aggregate "User" to something else and when getting data from the db map it from db entites to the aggregate.

I'm doing it wrong ? Or shouldn't i autogenerate the entities or is the enties aggregates ?

Plz advise and help.

[image]

Comment: I don't believe DDD work in your situation (if at all).  You have not separated your model from your infrastructure.

 1. Your entities are not in your domain, they exist in the infrastructure (bad).
 2. Your model is based on a database schema rather than what they're trying to model (bad).
 3. You're model is tied completley to EF rather than infrastructure agnostic (bad).

Comment: If i move the entites to the "Domain" can i use them as aggregates. but my model is exactly as my database schema. Maybe DDD was the wrong way to go with my project.

Comment: Don't know much about Entity Framework, but "DDD database first" sounds like an oxymoron. Can't you do code first instead ?

Comment: The thing is that the database design is already finished. It took us a long time to come up with it. Maybe we shuold skip DDD and just use EF. What we trying to build is a large WCF service.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to be true to DDD, you should model your domain objects to be independent of your persistence solution. DDD handles persistence through repositories. Don't use the "entities" generated by EF as your domain model; instead design your own model and implement a repository that makes use of EF for persistence.

Answer (score 3):

From my point of view, Domain-Driven Design and "database first" are antithetic. Domain-Driven design focuses on complex behavior, and a data model focuses on the static structure of the data.

If I had the privilege to start from a clean situation, I wouldn't make it more complicated than necessary by creating a legacy database first. Consider that DDD is oriented to complex domain, where discovery and learning is part of the process.

To support a continuous learning process it's better to rely on software components which are more specifically designed for evolution (like an Object-Oriented Domain Model that can be under cheap Unit Tests) instead of a database design whose evolution is definitely more expensive.

Nobody can do everything right at the beginning. So I'd better start with something with a very little throwaway cost.